# M5P Interpretations and Questions

Tags: regression, classification, cart

I need some advice when interpreting the output of the M5P model as shown below; I have some questions:

1. How is the 0.5 that determines the construction of each LM derived?
2. What do the numbers in the parentheses refer to?
3. What does 115% in LM8 mean? How can it be over 100%?

> ```
> region=1,3,4 <= 0.5 : LM1 (20000/19.779%)
> region=1,3,4 >  0.5 : 
> |   in-store=0 <= 0.5 : 
> |   |   region=4 <= 0.5 : 
> |   |   |   region=3,4 <= 0.5 : 
> |   |   |   |   age <= 55.5 : 
> |   |   |   |   |   age <= 31.5 : 
> |   |   |   |   |   |   age <= 24.5 : LM2 (1107/77.967%)
> |   |   |   |   |   |   age >  24.5 : LM3 (2649/71.098%)
> |   |   |   |   |   age >  31.5 : LM4 (8937/70.946%)
> |   |   |   |   age >  55.5 : LM5 (3307/37.787%)
> |   |   |   region=3,4 >  0.5 : LM6 (10999/37.952%)
> |   |   region=4 >  0.5 : LM7 (13001/77.69%)
> |   in-store=0 >  0.5 : LM8 (20000/115.636%)
> ```

I read in Wang & Whitten that the splits are supposed to be created by taking the SD(node.examples) <0.05*SD, but that doesnt match the output above.

Wang, Y., & Witten, I. H. (1996). Induction of model trees for predicting continuous classes.

Comment: What software program produced this outpout? M5P is an algorithm implemented in more than one program, so it is not clear from your question.

Answer (score 3):

1. `M5P` sets the split point mid-way between the two neighboring numeric values. So `age <= 55.5` means that observations with `age` up to `55` assigned to one node and starting from `56` to the other node. For categorical variables, dummy variables like `region=1,3,4` are constructed that can either be `0` or `1`. Hence, `M5P` sets the split point at `0.5`. One could argue that `region != 1,3,4` might have been more intelligible than `region=1,3,4 <= 0.5`. See also this discussion on the Weka mailing list: http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/Categorical-Variables-in-M5Rules-or-M5P-td17589.html.
2. The first number is simply the number of observations (aka instances) in that node. The second number gives the percentage of the RMSE *in that node* in relation to the RMSE of an intercept-only model *on the entire learning data*. (The latter RMSE is simply the standard deviation of the response/target variable on the full data.) See also this discussion on the Weka mailing list: http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/in-Regression-Tree-leafs-td36442.html#a36449.
3. The models are not nested because they pertain to different subsamples of the data set. Hence, the ratio of RMSEs can be larger than 100%.